# Subset rows that contain string in any column

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a dataset like below:

```
  Col1      Col2     Col3
abckel        NA        7
jdmelw     njabc       NA
     8     jdken     jdne
```

How do I subset my dataset so that it only keeps rows that contain the string "abc"?

Final Expected Output:

```
  Col1      Col2     Col3
abckel        NA        7
jdmelw     njabc       NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your data.frame:

```
d <- data.frame("Col1" = c("abckel", "jdmelw", 8),
                "Col2" = c(NA, "njabc", NA),
                "Col3" = c(7, NA, "jdne"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The following should return your desired result:

```
d_new <- d[apply(d, 1, function(x) any(grepl("abc", x))), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter_all(any_vars(grepl("abc", .)))
```

Output:

```
     Col1  Col2 Col3
1: abckel  <NA>    7
2: jdmelw njabc <NA>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  This doesn't work for me, even when I turn `df` into a data.table, which is what I think you did.

Comment: Still not sure how you're getting `df[grepl("abc", df)]` to work.  You're running `grepl()` on a list, which can produce unintended results.  I get no rows

Comment: Actually, `data.table` doesn't work here when I try to manually create a data frame and then running the code. Quite curious why it happens, as when `fread` turns it into a `DT` it runs fine. Have tested the `dplyr` solution and this works, have removed the other one.